# sql oracle - distinct missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query where i return all users, but they are users with the same TYPEUSER

```
select * from utilisateur ut where ut.TYPEUSER != 'classe' AND ut.TYPEUSER != 'user'
```

I tried with the below query to get unique users by TYPEUSER, but it returns this error `ORA-00936: missing expression`

```
select distinct ut.PRENOMUSER, * from utilisateur ut where ut.TYPEUSER != 'classe' AND ut.TYPEUSER != 'user'
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle allows `select *`.  But if you select other columns, you need to qualify the `*`.  So:

```
select distinct ut.PRENOMUSER, ut.*
from utilisateur ut
where ut.TYPEUSER <> 'classe' AND ut.TYPEUSER <> 'user';
```

This is just one of the syntactic weirdnesses of Oracle.  Another is that `as` is not permitted in the `FROM` clause (I wouldn't use it anyway).  I think it is because Oracle is the oldest database, long pre-dating the SQL standard.

Comment: with this query `select distinct ut.PRENOMUSER, ut.* from utilisateur ut where ut.PRENOMUSER = 'P-06-06';` i get two rows with the same PRENOMUSER "P-06-06"

Comment: @AymenKanzari . . . If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question.  This answers the question asked here.

Answer (score 1):

You dont even need `ut.PRENOMUSER` in select clause. it is irrelevant.

Use following query:

```
select distinct ut.*
from utilisateur ut
where ut.TYPEUSER <> 'classe' AND ut.TYPEUSER <> 'user';
```